# Windows 8.1 stuck in Automatic Repair boot loop - Proxmox VE

Tags: virtual-machines, boot, windows-8.1, proxmox

I installed Windows 8.1 64B in a VM on Proxmox-VE. It was running  fine for a few days until it needed to be rebooted (updates). First I tried reinstalling the OS which worked, until it needed to be rebooted and then it fell back into the loop of Automatic repair. It eventually ends in "Automatic repair couldn't repair your PC". I can't get it to boot at all.

What's even more concerning is that C:\ is listed as "System Reset" and I believe D:\ is my "boot" partition.

[image: Output of diskpart]

The `bootrec` command doesn't find an OS either.
[image: Output of bootrec /ScanOS]

Any ideas on how to fix this? How could this have happened? I let Windows automatically partition the drive during install.

Proxmox settings for the VM:
[image: Proxmox Settings 1]
[image: Proxmox Settings 2]

**I believe this issue is Proxmox related. Others have had these specific issues running Windows 8 in Proxmox. Ex. forum.proxmox.com/threads/14310-windows-8-1**

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Proxmox is a server virtualization management tool. https://www.proxmox.com/proxmox-ve

Comment: Yes, I aware of that :). However, judging from your problem description and your conversation with Somescout below, it doesn't  related to proxmox but to windows itself

Comment: I believe it is Proxmox related. Others have had these specific issues running Windows 8 in Proxmox. Ex. http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/14310-windows-8-1

Comment: Ahh... I wasn't aware of that. Please include that links in your question too, so other user/mod consider to reopen this question.

Comment: @masegaloeh, I figured out how to fix it. Harddrive must be set as IDE with write the write through option checked. The CPU must be only 1 socket 1 core and it must be set to Nehalem or SandyBridge.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there crash dump file in windows folder (%SystemDrive%:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP or file in \Windows\MiniDump) with corresponding date.

If file is there, you can analyze it with [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) (Open crash dump and !analyze) and see why system not starting.

Comment: I found the MEMORY.DMP file in D:\Windows, but how can I open it or take it out of the VM? I'm not actually logged into the PC, I got to the command prompt through the "Repair Your PC" recovery option.

Comment: Simplest way to copy it over network (if available):
1) use **wpeutil InitializeNetwork** to start network stack,  
2) check if it got address over dhcp: **ipconfig**  
3) authenticate on target share **net use \\computername\sharename /user:username password**  
4) Copy file.  
  
If somehow it not working, you can either mount virtual hard disk with system volume to another VM or mount some temporary virtual drive to this VM.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/E6pCGQT.png

Comment: Is there anyway I can force the system to boot from D:\ instead of C:\?

Comment: Can you ping gateway (10.0.2.2)?

Comment: Volume 1 contains BootManager. Normally (if system started successfully) it have no drive letter assigned, but during repair or WinPE boot - it will get it. So, it's not issue.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the gateway address.

Comment: Then network functioning correctly, check router settings.

Comment: Somescout the network is from the Proxmox host -- no router involved (this is a VM). If I put in a live ISO and boot from it, the network works on this VM.  All other systems on the host are not having network issues.

Comment: Maybe it's network driver issues (but still, you can ping gateway... try checking route tables). If you can boot from live cd and network works there, you can just mount system drive (in Windows or via NTFS3G in Linux) and transfer crash dump to another host. Or, again, you can mount system drive to another Windows VM and access it from there.